# Make space between table and section even to text and section

Tags: tables, spacing, parameters

Good evening,

I know that I can reduce the space that is inserted with a new table with \vspace*{-10pt}. But how to make it exactly even to the normal space between a \section or \subsection and the text?

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Die in dieser Arbeit benutzten Geräte.} \label{machines}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    \rowcolor[gray]{.6} Name & Funktion & Firma \\
    \hhline{===}
    TAdvanced & \multirow{3}{*}{Themocycler} & analytikjena \\
    MyCycler & & BioRad \\
    Mastercycler EP & & Eppendorf \\
    \hline
    Molecular Imager\textregistered  Gel Doc\texttrademark  XR System & Geldokumentationsanlage & BioRad \\
    \hhline{===}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: There is an extra space between the caption of the table and the "Geräte" section.]

Thanks in advance

Comment: please always provide a complete small test document that shows the issue. a `tabular` adds no space around the table so the space between a section heading and a following `tabular` is just that specified by the heading just as if a paragraph follows the heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the spacing around floats via changing the value `\intextsep`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl,multirow,hhline}
\begin{document}

\setlength\intextsep{0pt}

\section{Section title}
\subsection{Subsection title}
%
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Die in dieser Arbeit benutzten Geräte.} \label{machines}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    \rowcolor[gray]{.6} Name & Funktion & Firma \\
    \hhline{===}
    TAdvanced & \multirow{3}{*}{Themocycler} & analytikjena \\
    MyCycler & & BioRad \\
    Mastercycler EP & & Eppendorf \\
    \hline
    Molecular Imager\textregistered  Gel Doc\texttrademark  XR System & Geldokumentationsanlage & BioRad \\
    \hhline{===}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%
\subsection{Subsection title}
Subsection text here ...

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) How to change it back to standard? It should only be like that in this section because now the other tables and figures are hugging the text really close and it makes it kinda hard to read.

Comment: Just put the line `\setlength\intextsep{0pt}` and the table together between two curly braces, like this: `{\setlength\intextsep{0pt} \begin{table} .. \begin{table}}`. The command will affect only the current table.